# In vscode, lint errors show in problems, but lint error message not show when mouse hover red wave

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

[image]

Vscode info:

```
Version: 1.62.2
Date: 2021-11-11T20:59:05.913Z (2 days ago)
Electron: 13.5.2
Chrome: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 19.0.0
```

lint errors show in problems, but lint error message not show when mouse hover red wave.

Comment: same here, but using python linters

Comment: I have a similar issue. Note: you can use F8 to go to show the next linting error and Shift + F8 to show the previous linting error. This works in VS Code using flake8 for Python